# Material disappear in material preview node after pluging a bunch of textures combined

Tags: texturing

Material disappears in 'material preview' node after pluging a bunch of textures combined.
The color turns purple (like when there is no material detected. I have 10 textures combined with mix nodes, until then everything all right.
As soon as I put the 11th texture, the object turns purple in 'material preview' mode. Despite that everything works render-wise.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the entirety of your graph is comprised of, but I do know there is an upper-limit on the number of certain types of nodes in a graph (particularly image textures) that OpenGL will support. I _thought_ it was 24 image textures on windows systems and something like 8 or 16 for macs, but I could be wrong. Without knowing anything else, I think the over-abundance of image textures is likely to blame for your problem, and if that is the case, there really isn't much you can do to mitigate it other than using fewer image textures.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame because I using them to drive different section of a normal map to appear on bone transform, making wrinkles and lines to appear depending on the expression/limb position. The human body have several of these cases, even more that I intended to put here. Is there another way, like a layered texture plugin or something that solves the problem? Most other material-editing applications have a way to layer'em with nodes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. maybe some type of dynamically addressable texture atlas. through I imagine it would have to be pre-planned rather well. There's some discussion about the limitation and some possible workarounds (including the texture atlas) here, though the options are still rather limited. - https://blenderartists.org/t/maximum-number-of-image-texture-nodes-allowed/1313810

Comment: And plus: I'm dealing with UDIMs, which makes everything more complex. 6 UV slots to be precise. For each one single spot that I reveal in the texture, I have to make 5 more black textures to fill the non-appearing spaces... that means that, if I have 12 textures assigned, I have to have 72 textures for that. Blender won't reckognize a .1002 UDIM without the .1001 one and won't shade well without the other ones. That's dull! Of course I make the other textures a 16x16 size, because they are just solid black.